created user does not acess environment variable
I've followed these instructions to install tomcat on Ubuntu 22.04.
https://www.atlantic.net/dedicated-server-hosting/how-to-install-tomcat-10-on-ubuntu-22-04/
It worked on my laptop, but on my kvm virtual machine running Ubuntu 22.04, it says:
wardog1@server002:~$ journalctl -xeu tomcat.service

Dec 22 04:27:18 server002 startup.sh[1387]: This environment variable is needed to run this program
Dec 22 04:27:18 server002 startup.sh[1387]: NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
Dec 22 04:27:18 server002 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit tomcat.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.

  GNU nano 6.2                               /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service                                        
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat 11 Web Application Server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

Environment="JAVA_HOME=/home/wardog1/.sdkman/candidates/java/current"
Environment="CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat"
Environment="CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat"
Environment="CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid"
Environment="CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

The environment variables are identical in both machines but looks like JAVA_HOME is not been passed on to the tomcat user and can't be captured in the service
wardog1@server002:~$ env | grep java

JAVA_HOME=/home/wardog1/.sdkman/candidates/java/current
PATH=/home/wardog1/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin


What are the contents of /home/wardog1/.sdkman/candidates/java/current? Ideally, show us on both machines. Are they the same? I am asking because of the NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE; could this be the issue?

I created the same environment in both machines: my laptop and a kvm vm. I used the same names for login and even the same password. I suspect the cause is sdkman is the root user home folder and the tomcat user has its own environment. What I don't understand is why it worked in my laptop

I also suspect the cause has something to do with the ssh connection between the host (laptop) and the kvm vm.

Still, can you please show us the contents of the JAVA_HOME directories on both machines? And please explain what you mean about the root user. Add that to your question.

I'd install java with sdkman and both folders have the same content. /home/wardog1/.sdkman/candidates/java/current. The problem is the tomcat user does have access to this folder in the laptop and does not have in the vm. JAVA_HOME Is empty when the tomcat.service runs

Again: please add this to the question! If there is a permissions issue, show us the permissions for all the directories that need to be traversed to get to your Java installation. Most likely you need to add the tomcat user to the right groups but we can't know 8f you don't show us.

the problem was the use of sdkman.
sdkman installs the jdk in the user's home and the tomcat user does not have access to the environment of the logged user.
the solution was to give up sdkman and install jdk directly.
Also, I had to set JAVA_HOME in /etc/environment.
Another clue I have is the difference between the default profile in my laptop and the vm
laptop
wardog1@wardog1-Aspire-A315-23:~$ ls -ld /home/wardog1/
drwxr-xr-x 58 wardog1 wardog1 4096 dez 24 03:42 /home/wardog1/

vm
wardog1@server001:~$ ls -ld /home/wardog1/
drwxr-x--- 5 wardog1 wardog1 4096 Dec 22 20:18 /home/wardog1/

The lack of execution permission on my home folder caused the jdk fail the execution of tomcat.service

My only doubt is whether this was the reason why JAVA_HOME was not set


